# Puppet unable to find my .erb template but finds other files OK?

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

No one has been able to explain this inside my company so if you are able to solve this KUDOS to you!

Inside my puppet repo I have setup as follows:

```
environment/ops/modules/papertrail
    ├── files
    │   ├── elasticsearch_log_files.yml
    │   ├── log_files.yml
    │   └── remote_syslog.conf
    |  
    └── manifests 
        ├── elasticsearch.pp
        └──init.pp
    └── templates
        └── elasticsearch_log_files.yml.erb
```

MY elasticsearch.pp file contains the following:

```
class papertrail::elasticsearch inherits papertrail {

      $source = "puppet:///modules/papertrail"

      file { "/etc/log_files.yml" :
        mode         => 0644,
        owner        => root,
        group        => root,
        ensure       => present,
        source       => "$source/elasticsearch_log_files.yml",
      }
    }
```

Now when I try to change the last line to:

"$source/elasticsearch_log_files.yml.erb",

or

"$source/templates/elasticsearch_log_files.yml",

Puppet errors out and says that it can't locate the file:

Error: /Stage[main]/Papertrail::Elasticsearch/File[/etc/log_files.yml]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment ops source(s) puppet:///modules/papertrail/elasticsearch_log_files.yml.erb

What is strange is that when I use the following stanza to just include the yml file instead of erb it works fine and the file gets populated on the target:

```
 "$source/elasticsearch_log_files.yml",
```

How can I include my erb? I have dynamic variables that I need to assign to the configuration file log_files.yml and I am so far unable to do so =(

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I didn't add the template directory to my git commit so once added with git add . it worked.